# como mostrar en una tabla con la información separada?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angular15

tengo un array de esta forma

```
{
 0: {id: 4229954, clave: '21d', descripcion: 'Número de expediente', valor: '6092'}
 1: {id: 4229954, clave: '22', descripcion: 'Fecha de presentación', valor: '02/01/1905'}
 2: {id: 4229954, clave: '54', descripcion: 'Título', valor: '"Dila"'}
 3: {id: 4229955, clave: '21d', descripcion: 'Número de expediente', valor: '6093'}
 4: {id: 4229955, clave: '22', descripcion: 'Fecha de presentación', valor: '03/01/1905'}
 5: {id: 4229955, clave: '54', descripcion: 'Título', valor: 'maquina para hacer tortilla'}
}
```

cada descripción es una columna, como se puede ver del 0 al 2 son una celda y del 3 al 5 es otra
debo mostrarlo en una tabla
trate de poner

```
<div *ngFor="let data of fichas" >
  <div  *ngIf= "descripcion == 'Número de expediente'">
    {{data.valor}}
  </div>
</div>
```

pero me muestra la información salteada en forma diagonal

la idea es que me salga

```
Número de expediente | Fecha de presentación | Título
6092                   02/01/1905              Dila
6093                   03/01/1905              maquina para hacer tortilla
```

alguna idea?